# How to check if user exists in user provider database

Tags: symfony, provider

I am developing an API with Oauth2 authentication with Symfony framework. 
For this i created a custom user provider which i use to log in. That works well.

What i need to do now is to send a message to another user, only if that user is defined in my system (= user exits in user provider database). 
This "message sending" function is made in another bundle than the user provider bundle.

So my question is : how to check if the message recipient does exit in user provider database, using user provider functions ?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which Database system you use, but for now I'll just stick to SQL. You could use this example:

You should get the id using php. I assume you know how to do so!

```
$id = #YourId;
```

You can now use the following query to select the user in your database:

```
SELECT * FROM [user_table] WHERE id = $id;
```

Then, you could use php to check whether the query has result. If it has a result, you'll know the user exists, if it doesn't, then the user does not exist!

I hope this helps you out. Don't forget to mark this question as completed if you've come a little further!